# From what I understood vs understand

Tags: difference, tense

> From what I **understood**, …
> From what I **understand**, …

I always have trouble telling which one to use whenever asking a question, writing an email, etc. Are they interchangeable or are they used in different contexts?

Comment: From what I understood at a time in the past, something was the case; from what I understand now, something is the case.

Answer (score 1):

"*From what I **understood**, ...*" means, "*Based on something specific that I read/saw/heard/etc. in the past, I think ... is true.*"

"*From what I **understand**, ...*" means more simply, "*I think ... is true.*" With this version, you can think it is true for any reason, including something you read/saw/heard/etc. in the past, or anything else in your life that leads you to think it's true.